# Use javascript to sort an array of ints by the distance the element is from a given target

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, sorting

Algorithm: distanceSort(array, target)

Input: An array of ints **sorted** from least to greatest and an int to measure distance from

Output: The array sorted by distance from target

**Example**

distanceSort([-10,-6,3,5], 1)

returns [3, 5, -6, -10]

Comment: What is your question and what have you tried? Do you have any code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a way to do it. Using [`Array.sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/sort) function

```
var a = [-10, -6, 3, 5, 99, 76, -100];

function distanceSort(arr, target) {
   return arr.sort(function(a, b) {
      var distance1 = Math.abs(target - a);
      var distance2 = Math.abs(target - b);

      return distance1 == distance2 ? 0 : (distance1 > distance2 ? 1 : -1);
   });
}

console.log(distanceSort(a, 100)); //[99,76,5,3,-6, -10, -100]
console.log(distance(a, -5)); //[-6, -10, 3, 5, 76, -100, 99]
```

Comment: Interesting solution. The input array is sorted from least to greatest though. This algorithm doesnt take advantage of that. Any idea of the time complexity of your solution though?

Comment: I missed the input array being sorted from least to greatest, but that doesn't change the output. I'll give you the way, you can finish the rest ;). I din't stop to think about the since the question wasn't about performance.

Answer (score 2):

First, perform a binary search (I always copy [from here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/lower_bound/)) to find the target inside the array (if it exists, or the immediatelly greater otherwise).

Then, keep two pointers moving in oposing directions adding always the element with less distance from the target.

The binary search is O(log n) and moving the pointers is O(n). The overall algorithm is O(n).

```
function lowerBound(arr, target) {
    var first = 0, 
        count = arr.length;

    while (count > 0) {
        var step = count / 2;
        var it = first + step;

        if (arr[it] < target) {
            first = it + 1;
            count -= step + 1;
        } else {
            count = step;
        }
    }

    return first;
}

function distanceSort(arr, target) {
    var answer = [];

    var j = lowerBound(arr, target);
    var i = j-1;

    while (i >= 0 || j<arr.length) {
        if (j >= arr.length || target-arr[i]<arr[j]-target)
            answer.push(arr[i--]);
        else
            answer.push(arr[j++]);
    }
    return answer;
}

console.log(distanceSort([-10,-6,3,5], 1));   //[3, 5, -6, -10]
console.log(distanceSort([-10,-6,3,5], -11)); //[-10, -6, 3, 5]
console.log(distanceSort([-10,-6,3,5], -10)); //[-10, -6, 3, 5]
console.log(distanceSort([-10,-6,3,5], 5));   //[5, 3, -6, -10]
console.log(distanceSort([-10,-6,3,5], 6));   //[5, 3, -6, -10]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var distanceSort = function distanceSort(nArr, x){
    return nArr.sort(function(n1, n2){
        return Math.abs(n1 - x) - Math.abs(n2 - x);
    });
}

console.log(distanceSort([-10,-6, 57, 54, 11, -34, 203, -140, 3, 5], 1));
//--> [3, 5, -6, 11, -10, -34, 54, 57, -140, 203]
```

It translates nicely into ECMA6 (if you're using Babel) :

```
var distanceSort = (nArr, x) => 
    (nArr.sort((n1, n2) =>
        (Math.abs(n1 - x) - Math.abs(n2 - x))));
```

Comment: i like that you use ECMA6 but the previous answer posted uses almost the same exact function

Comment: Yeah, I saw that after I posted...but I left it anyway since I'd included the ECMA6 section.

Comment: Do you know if this runs in O(n logn)?

Comment: Probably, given the number of comparisons sort does. Yeah, it's likely not an optimized solution. I've only used the sort function for smaller sorts, so I haven't had any problems with it, but I doubt it scales well.